# Reference Request: Basis for the null space via column reduction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

There is this very nice method [laid out on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)#Computation_by_Gaussian_elimination) for how to compute a basis for the null space of a matrix via column reduction. It's so satisfying that I've started teaching it and have even included it in some notes I'm trying to publish. I have yet to see it reference-able in any textbook I'm familiar with.

Does anyone know of a reference for the method I linked to?

Comment: I’ve never seen this before in 40+ years of teaching linear algebra. It does correspond, essentially, to the standard method of finding the *left nullspace* (nullspace of the transpose) by row operations. This is in many textbooks — including Strang’s and my own — but is rarely taught.

Comment: That said, I’m not sure I find it a sound pedagogical choice. Most of my strongest students found it confusing to switch to column operations, having mastered row operations. And I rarely had time to cover everything I wanted to, as it was.

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin thank you for acknowledging how this method rarely shows up in references! I can see that pedagogically it feels like a distraction. I sort of forced it on my students because I was trying to give them a taste of some computations in topology where you find bases for kernel and image of two maps AB = 0 simultaneously. The students *actually* said they liked learning this column method for the null space. But my other motivation is that it's easier (imo) to write an algorithm with, i.e. teach a computer. This is a big deal for how I motivate calculations these days :)

Comment: p.s. now I have to check out your book hah!